# I have the google+ userid. but now google+ is shutdown. So how can i get email id using the google+ id?

Tags: google-api, google-plus

I only have my friend google+ account id to contact my friend.Now google+ is not working. So how I can get the email address of the friend using the google+ id? Is there any way to get the email address using the google+ id?

Answer (score 1):

Google+ was shut down in Early apirl 2019 since that time there is no longer anyway to use it or its api.

Even before this time there was now way for you to get someones email address just by knowing their google+ id.  You would need someones permission to access their email address.